# How to edit google cloud VM instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to add memory to my instance. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-drO_2P6Xnc) explains it, but sadly I don't have the "edit" button. How do I edit my instance?

[Screenshot of what "VM instances" look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqMCP.png)

Answer (score 0):

So actually I found the answer, first you have to double click on the instance you want to edit and only then does the "edit" button appear, as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#create_disk).

Answer (score 0):

To add more memory to a Vm instance, first you need to stop the VM instance in order to be able to change the [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance)to one with more memory, since the quantity of memory is defined by the different [machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types).